How do I use Kalman Filter for data with error accumulation
I use UKF for robot localization (via FilterPy). I understand how to do implementation in general, and GPS sensor already works.
My question is about adding odometry from dif. drive. Odometry errors accumulate, so if I provide the filter with (x,y,heading) from ROS2 dif. drive odometry, it will become more and more garbage. I thought that if I use velocity/angular velocity instead, I'll be fine because those do not accumulate error. But what I see is improvement, compared to GPS-only case, at the beginning, but then it looks identical to GPS-only.


On the charts, black line is a ground truth trajectory.
So my question is, what data should I use from ROS2 /odom to provide to UKF, and how does it work?
Once again, I know how Kalman filter works in general, and how to implement it. I need some kind of human language explaination of how can it use data that accumulates errors.
Thank you.
Addition: filter's code. Few things.

When feeding the sensor data, it assumes that odometry is just pos + noise. It is probably ok for rough testing, but it will not accumulate the error (so, TBD).

I use the following state: x,y,theta.
In order to have access to speed and acceleration, I have to keep "previous values" of these variables. There is an obvious alternative: to add it all to a state: x,y,theta, velocity, acceleration, angular velocity...
I do not know if this is necessary, or to put it differently, I do not know if keeping the previous state is wrong.

The code above works (just run it with Python3), but due to (2), it will produce nice looking charts for odometry, without error accumulation. To see error accumulation, I used ROS2 (I am not providing full code, as I don't believe anyone will want to spend time running all that). The charts below are obtained from ROS2 simulation. That way, odometry errors for position do accumulate - but I do not use position anyway, I use speed and angular speed (position comes from GPS).

In the code I provide, you can comment/uncomment any combination of sensors in dictSensors.


Code (sorry, cannot properly format on StackOverflow):
https://robotics.snowcron.com/kalman_3.txt

Do you know for sure that the linear/angular velocity aren't integrated from IMU as well? I would think that velocities would have the same problem of errors accumulating.
IIRC the odom messages are often the outputs of a filter anyway. In your position I would probably dig into what gets fed into that filter. (It's probably something like wheel encoder and IMU) Over short durations, that data should be fairly accurate, and you can use that in the filter prediction step.
Depending on how well you know your noise models, you might just need to tune your filter a bit. I'm a little unclear on what your plots are showing, but in the first plot it looks like the filter is performing fairly well.

I am not talking about IMU (yet, it is in my to do list). I am talking about dif. drive. And unlike IMU, dif. drive does not accumulate errors about speed (it knows how wheels rotate, so speed in robot frame does not drift, am I correct?) and angular speed.
So my question was about those. In ROS2, this is the /odom topic, and source of data is 0 (encoder).
The first plot is GPS only, the second is GPS + Odometry.

You mentioned "and you can use that in the filter prediction step". Are you suggesting using GPS in correction step, and odometry in prediction? I thought that Kalman filter should get all data alltogether?

Yeah, it's called doing "model replacement". (I tried finding a good freely available reference but I couldn't find anything. You can search google scholar for '"model replacement" kalman filter' and see if any papers come up from sources that you have access to)

Okay, so what does your dynamics model look like and what do your measurement models look like?

Actually, this paper discusses model replacement fairly well. It's on arxiv, so you should be able to view it.
Costley, Austin, et al. "Path Planning with Uncertainty for Aircraft Under Threat of Detection from Ground-Based Radar." arXiv preprint arXiv:2207.03716 (2022).

Added code for the filter: no installation, except for FilterPy; just run the file.

I can't view your code, I get a 404 error. To post it on stackoverflow you should just be able to do python  

That's because I forgot the underscore: kalman3.txt instead of kalman_3.txt.
Fixed.

The biggest thing that I notice is that the odometry function doesn't depend on x or y, so it doesn't add much information to the filter. I'm not surprised that it doesn't do much better than GPS-only in the long-run. Odometry is mainly helpful in the stretches without GPS measurements, since having an IMU measurement is often better than your dynamics model. If you wanted to illustrate the benefit of odometry, you could try adding a stretch without GPS/landmark measurements?

Please explain. "Odometry function doesn't depend on x or y" - is it my error, or is it supposed to be that way?
Also, I understand the idea with stretch: when no GPS, use odometry, right? But I thought Kalman should fuse GPS and odometry, so when no GPS, odometry is used automatically? So what should I change?

And one more question: what should odometry effect be, if I do everything right? What to expect? Will accuracy increase? Or will it be just like with GPS, plus some improvement when no GPS?

Also also :)
For odometry, what is a "physical sense" of a sigma? Is it an error compared to previous measurement?
Let's say I have a "common" average dif.drive and Kalman works every 0.1 second: what a sigma for odometry should I set and why?

Your measurement function needs to depend on your state variables for it to be of any use to the filter. Look at your GPS function, for example, which directly measures x and y. If the filter's estimate of x is 3 meters and the measurement of x is 8 meters, the filter will increase its estimate of x. Your odom function doesn't depend on position at all, and so it can't really help you with positioning.

Addressing your second question and something that I saw in the code---your Q matrix is /really/ small. Barely any process noise is added. The benefit of odometry would be that it can correct for process noise. Like if your dynamics are noisy and the prediction is that the vehicle traveled 2 meters in one time step but the wheel encoder only measured 1.7, then the filter would adjust its position a little bit. With barely any process noise, there is really nothing for odometry to help with.

The odometry sigma would, in reality, depend on the sensor accuracy. Definition of measurement covariance is E[(z_true - z_measured)^2]. For a simulation you can just set it to be a moderate value. It'll work fine as long as the value that you set is consistent between the filter and the simulator.


Your measurement function needs to depend on your state variables for it to be of any use to the filter.

Are you saying that I have to put in Hx(...) for "odom" something like x[0] + v*cos(theta)*dt? I thought I need to put data there that are same type as sensor measurement?

Well, I guess, the right question is, what should be changed in this code, if I want to have state as x,y,theta while sensor measures speed and angular speed?
